# How to run git commands in .net solution build pipeline in gitlab

Tags: .net, git, docker, msbuild, gitlab-ci

I have a .net repository which is dependent on another repository so I am using the other repository as submodule.

I am using this docker image to build the repository

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk
```

But to use the submodule I have to get the latest of the submodule and that can be done using the git commands like this

```
before_script:
  - git submodule sync --recursive
  - git submodule update --init --recursive
```

but the git command is not available in the docker image and so it fails saying `git is not recognized`

Can anyone help me what should be done to have git available?

I have tried many things like dividing the build in two stages and try to use different docker image for git etc. but nothing is exactly working for my requirement.

**Update**

This is `.gitlab-ci.yml` file including the solution that `jmaitrehenry` suggested in his answer

```
stages:
   - build


variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

before_script:
    - docker build -t git-for-windows-issue

# Build
Build:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo Ok
  only:
    - branches
  tags:
    - windows-runner
  environment:
    name: development
```

But that is also giving this error

> docker : The term 'docker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or  if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your gitlab runner is not too old (v1.10+), you can add this in your pipeline:

```
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
```

With that, gitlab will do the sync and update for you when it clone/prepare the project.

If you can't, you will need to install git in your image. You can check this repo to help you with git on windows: https://github.com/StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows/tree/master/git-for-windows-issue
You can add this to the before_script:

```
before_script:
  - Invoke-WebRequest 'https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.15.1.windows.2/MinGit-2.15.1.2-busybox-64-bit.zip' -OutFile 'mingit.zip' -UseBasicParsing
  - Expand-Archive mingit.zip -DestinationPath c:\mingit ; \
  - Remove-Item mingit.zip -Force ; \
  - c:\mingit\cmd\git.exe submodule sync --recursive
  - c:\mingit\cmd\git.exe submodule update --init --recursive
```

Gitlab doc: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html
How to install git on windows:

Comment: I am already using this `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive` and it does say that it is updating modules but doesn't seem to do anything. And I tried to install few things with docker but the problem is even docker command is not working with this image it give this error `docker : The term 'docker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, `

Comment: Can you add your gitlab-ci.yml file with the gitlab and runner version? And, gitlab run the script instruction inside the container, it's why you doesn't have docker. You can check one of the dockerfile from my link to see how git is installed and try to do the same in the `before_script`

Comment: I am posting the very basic version of my yml file in the question that I am trying to run. Please check

Comment: I add more instruction about git on windows, can you add the gitlab version and the gitlab-runner version too?

Comment: Gitlab version - `GitLab Enterprise Edition 12.10.6-ee`. I don't know how to check gitlab runner version, we have a shared runner with name `windows-build-machine` and tag `windows-runner`

Comment: After putting the before script that you added now, it started giving error on the first line for wrong syntax `- [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`, so I commented it and then ran but again got `git is not recognized` error

Comment: I updated the before script to add the complete git.exe path, hope this will help. For the gitlab runner version, you can get it in the admin: http://mygitlab/admin/runners

Comment: Thanks Man!! It worked :) Upvoted and selected your answer :) Just two questions, why didn't this line work `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` and why didn't path got set with this, `- setx /M PATH $('c:\mingit\cmd;{0}' -f $env:PATH)`

Comment: For setx, I forgot one point about it: Setx writes variables to the master environment in the registry. Variables set with setx variables are available in future command windows only, not in the current command window.
And for the first line, I don't know honestly :/ Happy that you have a solution for your problem!

Comment: Okay, thanks :)
Whenever you have time if you can see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932481/one-specific-nuget-package-is-not-getting-pushed-to-gitlab I posted would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use cake script which will handle other .net build process as well and you can create reusable task
https://cakebuild.net/dsl/git/